# Replacing a Galaxy S10 internal storage

Tags: samsung, internal-storage, data-recovery, hardware

I have an old Samsung Galaxy S10 that's completely smashed up. I've been trying to recover the data for some time now. The issue I'm having is when I charge it up and power it on, it sounds like it's just continuously boot looping which is stopping it from detecting any files on the device.

I'm kind of out of options on how to solve this issue.

Would it be possible to buy another S10 device and install the flash drive from my old device onto the new one? I've been searching on Google and struggling to find any answers.

Comment: What you call " flash drive" is a flash chip soldered onto the phone's mainboard. Usually such chips use ball grid connection which makes (de)soldering them very complicated and even may required special tools. Another problem is that the data on the chip is encrypted. I don't know if the decryption key is bound to the other hardware or not. If it is bound then all the soldering would be useless because on a new mainboard the data could not be decrypted.

Comment: would installing the whole motherboard into the new device be viable maybe? not sure what damage has been done on the inside tbf, dont suppose you know of any other way to salvage the storage?

Comment: Possible but I don't have any experience on this. You should better visit a smartphone repair shop, they have the experience to tell you what is possible and what not. Especially they can look at the damage.